# Sequence of division by powers of 10 (Dafny)

Tags: dafny

Why do these assertions fail?

```
ghost function IntValues(n: nat) : seq<nat>
{
    if n == 0 then [0]
    else [n] + IntValues(n/10)
}

method test_IntValues(number: nat)
{
    ghost var nvals := IntValues(number);
    assert 0 in nvals;
    assert number/10 in nvals;
}
```

This is part of a larger problem I'm trying to solve, but this not working makes it clear that I'm missing something fundamental. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why `assert 0 in nvals` is failing ?

No amount of fuel parameter (unrolling of definition) will cover this case as `nat` can be arbitrary large. To able to prove this we need specification attach to function. This will allow dafny to use specification to prove fact about `IntValue`, instead of doing prove by computation (by unrolling definition upto some limit).

```
ghost function IntValues(n: nat) : (r: seq<nat>)
  ensures 0 in r
{
    if n == 0 then [0]
    else [n] + IntValues(n/10)
}

method test_IntValues(number: nat)
{
    ghost var nvals := IntValues(number);
    assert 0 in nvals;
}
```

Another option is to prove some lemma about `IntValue`.

```
lemma NumbersInIntValue(n: nat)
 ensures 0 in IntValues(n)
 ensures n/10 in IntValues(n)
{}
```

Then use lemma to prove `0 in nvals`.

```
method test_IntValues(number: nat)
{
    ghost var nvals := IntValues(number);
    NumbersInIntValue(number);
    assert 0 in nvals;
    assert number/10 in nvals;
}
```

---

For function we need to keep in mind there are two different cases.

- When parameter is concrete value.

In case parameter is concrete value, dafny uses bigger fuel to
compute answer. Bigger fuel means more unrolling of definition.
This is reason dafny is able to verify below program.

```
method Test()
{
  var t := IntValues(202);
  assert 0 in t;
}
```

- When parameter is symbolic value.

In case parameter is symbolic value, dafny uses smaller fuel. I think
this value is 1. In your case it is trying to prove `0 in [n] ++ <opaque seq>` when n is not zero. If you increase fuel to 2. It will be try in `[n] ++ (if n/10 == 0 then [0] else [n/10] ++ <opaque seq>)`. Using fuel 2, you can see it able to prove `n/10 in nvals`, but not `0 in nvals` (case when n/10 is not equal to 0). As you might guess increasing fuel will not help this case as fuel parameter is finite integer.

To prove cases like this we need bottom up approach which specification and lemma enables. When using lemma/specification(ensures) it will try to prove case when n is 0 first which is trivial. Case when n is not zero, it can use induction hypothesis to proceed.

Comment: ah, interesting! We can also `ensure n/10 in r`! That's solves everything. Thanks! I confess I'm still very confused about what Dafny can and can't verify by itself. If it can verify the statements in ensures, why wouldn't it be able to verify them in asserts right after the call to IntValues?

Comment: I have added another paragraph with explanation.